# How to update table from another table on a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I've found the following code to update table from another table,

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import
SET
    Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM
    Sales_Import SI
INNER JOIN
    RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
ON 
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID
```

but can I do if the tables are on different servers, and one of them is local ?

Comment: How to update a table from one server to another?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497503/how-to-update-a-table-from-one-server-to-another

Answer (score 0):

Adham, I believe you can do a dump of the table and unload it into the other database:

```
mysqldump -uYOUR_USER -p db-name-from tablename | mysql -uYOUR_USER -p -h server-to db-name-to
```

It is basically two concatenated actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try mirroring (replication) if its mysql.
Or try to cluster.
Well this point was overtaken in Oracle database using public database links

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has database connections, which allow you to work in one database, and connect to a totally different database, on a totally different server. SQL-Server has this functionality too, but there it is called a database link.

However, as far as I know, MySQL does not have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linked Servers. In this case, you should use the format {server_name}.{database_name}.{schema_name}.{table_name} to identify the tables on other servers.

If one of the tables (RetrieveAccountNumber, for example) is on another server (you can name it as A), and one is local, then you can rewrite your query as:

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import
SET
    Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM
    Sales_Import SI
INNER JOIN
    A.{the_database_name}.{schema_name}.RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
ON 
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this through SQL query then you’ll need to setup linked servers and use syntax similar to what Enhnaran posted.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) is a general info on linked servers and [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) on how to set it up

If you need to do this one time only then you can also consider SQL Server Import / Export wizard for this.