# How to update a table from one server to another?

Tags: mysql, select, insert-update

I need to do an update from one server to another and could only get to the code that are below.
I wanted to know where the mistake is.

If separating the codes works perfectly.

```
<?PHP
$db_host1     = "10.0.0.101";
$db_user1     = "dns";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "dns";
$db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$db_host2     = "10.0.0.102";
$db_user2     = "dns";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "dns";
$db_connect2  = mysqli_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_password2, $db_name2);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($db_connect2,"UPDATE ipserver SET ipsserver = ($db_connect1,"SELECT ipsserver FROM ipserver WHERE idserver = '11'") WHERE idserver = '11'");

mysqli_close($db_connect1);
mysqli_close($db_connect2);
?>
```

Thanks to @Jon Dinham for helping me solve my problem

I'll put the script already corrected

```
<?PHP
$db_host1     = "10.0.0.101";
$db_user1     = "dns";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "dns";
$db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$db_host2     = "10.0.0.102";
$db_user2     = "dns";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "dns";
$db_connect2  = mysqli_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_password2, $db_name2);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query(
$db_connect1,
"SELECT ipsserver FROM ipserver WHERE idserver='11'"
);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

foreach ($rows as $index=>$row) {
$ipsserver = $row;

mysqli_query(
$db_connect2,
"UPDATE ipserver SET ipsserver='$ipsserver' WHERE idserver='11'"
);
}

mysqli_close($db_connect1);
mysqli_close($db_connect2);
?>
```

Comment: I am afraid you'll need a loop to read from one and insert to another.

Comment: Ok and how do I do that?

Comment: Just like @jon did. There's an implicit cursor under you connection abstraction. There's no Magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up MySQL replication (master/slave) and execute the queries on the master DB only. See documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html

For just 1 time querying, replace the line:

```
mysqli_query($db_connect2,"UPDATE ipserver SET ipsserver = ($db_connect1,"SELECT ipsserver FROM ipserver WHERE idserver = '11'") WHERE idserver = '11'");
```

with this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query(
  $db_connect1,
  "SELECT ipsserver FROM ipserver WHERE idserver='11'"
);

while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $ipsserver = $row["ipsserver"];

  mysqli_query(
    $db_connect2,
    "UPDATE ipserver SET ipsserver='$ipsserver' WHERE idserver='11'"
  );
}
```

Comment: I just need to update this field don' t want to do major alterations in the system

Comment: added details for your wanted case

Comment: Thank you for your work 

but I am still receiving an error

    `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in on line 25`

it is at

    `$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Thanks to @Jon Dinham for helping me solve my problem.

I'll put the script already fixed on top.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_all is available only from php 5.3, i've updated the code to use 'while' loop instead

Comment: Hello again 

And if I need to copy all that inside the table. 

Thanks again